# Как сделать кнопку "Сделать стартовой" средствами html или javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как сделать кнопку "Сделать стартовой" средствами html или javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Делаем файлик bookmark.js

```
function add_favorite(a){title="Заголок";url="http://www.site.ru";try{window.external.AddFavorite(url,title)}catch(e){try{window.sidebar.addPanel(title,url,"")}catch(e){if(typeof(opera)=="object"){a.rel="sidebar";a.title=title;a.url=url;return true}else{alert('Нажмите Ctrl-D чтобы добавить страницу в закладки')}}}return false}
```

подключаем к странице в секцию < head>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bookmark.js"></script>
```

делаем ссылку

```
<a href="http://www.site.ru/" onclick="return add_favorite(this)" title="Добавить страницу в избранное">
```

Кроссбраузерное решение.

Comment: Но, ведь этот скрипт для того, что бы страницу добавить в закладки а не сделать стартовой!

Comment: Ооо да, это я тупанул, пардон. xD

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('http://www.site.com');">Сделать стартовой</a>
```

Но насколько мне известно это работает только в IE. Для остальных браузеров к сожалению пока не видел ни одного решения.